# Why we defined tangent?

Tags: calculus, math-history, tangent-line

Tangent to a function at a point is defined precisely by calculus. But at first, what made us define tangent? Why is it important?

Comment: A tangent line is a good approximation to a differentiable function in a neighborhood of the point of tangency

Comment: Tangent was already present in Euclid's [Elements](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookIII/bookIII.html), well before calculus.

Comment: This is slightly off topic (tangential?), but I think this visual depiction of the trigonometric tanget provides some intuitive insight: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#/media/File:Circle-trig6.svg .  Similar triangles in this picture can be used to reason out the standard definition $\tan{\theta} = \dfrac{\sin{\theta}}{\cos{\theta}}$.

Comment: Find a calculus book! It will contain _many_ examples of why derivatives are useful...

Comment: Consider a particle who travels in one dimension and is at point $f(t)$ at time $t$.  The question of finding the average velocity of the particle over a particular time interval is simply $\dfrac{f(t_1)-f(t_0)}{t_1-t_0}$, that is, the change in distance over the change in time.  The derivative gives us a way to talk about the instantaneous speed at a particular time, it merely being the limit as we consider the average speeds as the interval of time we are considering keeps getting smaller and smaller around our desired point in time we are interested in.

Comment: I recommend watching Herbert Gross's video series: [Calculus Revisited](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFRWDuduuSw&list=PL3B08AE665AB9002A).

Comment: Way before calculus why we defined tangent?

Comment: *Way before calculus why we defined tangent?* --- Possibly helpful is [History of the derivative/tangent of a curve](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/5006/264).